# Year 10 Maths Question Range of Function

Tags: functions

Can someone explain to me the range for this particular function please

$$ y= \frac {2} {\sqrt{4-x^2}} $$

I'm in Year 10 so can someone explain this to me in a simple way.

Don't really get why it is y larger than or equal to 1

But I know the bottom cannot be equal to 0

Comment: $$\infty>\sqrt{4-x^2}\ge0\implies\infty>\dfrac1{\sqrt{4-x^2}}>0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular function, lets consider the bottom first

We know that for the square root, $$ \sqrt {4-x^2} $$ that the values that this can exist only range from 0 to 2. This is because the value for x by itself can only exist up to x=2, because any larger would mean 4 subtracting number larger than 4, where the square root of a negative number DOES NOT EXIST. Hence the max limit of x is 2. This is mirrored on the negative x axis since x has been squared.

Therefore for,  $$ \sqrt {4-x^2} $$, then $$ 0 \leq  \sqrt {4-x^2} \leq 2$$

Then if you place this over the function in the question, we can sub the limits of this range to test for particular values, e.g. 
$$ y= \frac 2 2 $$ is equal to 1, and also
$$ \frac 2  {\text{very small number close to zero}} $$ becomes a very large number headed towards infinity.

OBVIOUSLY, the 0 cannot be the denominator because this is invalid

As such the range of values exist from 1 to a very large number so, $$ y \geq 1 $$

Comment: I made an edit for the denominator of the last fraction just to make it looking nicer. I hope you don't mind. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$ then $y=1$. For all other $x$ the denominator is smaller than $2$ so $y$ is greater than $1$

$2\ge \sqrt{4-x^2}$ for any $x\in(-2,2)$

indeed $4\ge 4-x^2$ means $x^2\ge 0$ which is always true in $(-2,2)$

Answer (score 1):

The domain is $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid -2 < x < 2\}$.

Since the function has $y$-axis symmetry, to find the range, we only need to consider the restricted domain $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 \le x < 2\}$.

As $x$ continuously increases from $0$ to $2$, not including $2$,

- $4-x^2$ continuously decreases from $4$ to $0$, not including $0$.$\\[4pt]$

  $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ continuously decreases from $2$ to $0$, not including $0$.$\\[4pt]$

  ${\large{\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}}}$ continuously increases, starting at $1$, and approaches infinity, as $x$ approaches $0$ from above.

It follows that the range is $\{y \in \mathbb{R} \mid y \ge 1\}$.